# Android Build size is high if use phonegap with single html page

Tags: cordova

After building app with phonegap I just come to know app size for android (.apk file )is **mb** even if I am not using anything. It is just a default or sample app which is having only index.html file with text `Hello Phonegap`.

What I did i tell you , I created one folder named www which is having index.html file. I ziped the folder and by using https://build.phonegap.com/ ,I am building .apk file. I downloaded the file and size is big , It should be in KB.

Same app i created in **native android** using eclipse it is **in KB**.

Why there is a difference in size. Is it the case where phonegap is using any default cordova library which is big in size.

Comment: which version of cordova ? If your using cordova < 3.0 by default all the plugins would be part of ur apk making ur app bigger in size

Comment: Latest one above 3.0.

Comment: Inside your www folder check if res folder is der . If yes remove unwanted image from it